# A Global In-App Home Button

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Building an interface, but I need a button, let's say its a round HOME button, that sits in the lower-right of the screen, that is always there, and will always return you back to the main screen.

It makes senses in the context of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Is there a clever/elegant way to do this, or am I restricted to just making a version of the Navigation Controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here you need to play somehow with navigation controller. In the bottom of application stack there is always `RootViewController`, over which all other controller pushed in the application stack with respect to application window.

So just follow these steps to fulfill your question requirments.

Assign `RootViewController` to your `HomeViewController` (On which you want to come again and again via a right bottom most of screen).

```
HomeViewController *homeViewController = self.window.rootViewController;
```

And Every time When click on that "Right most bottom button " call this.

```
[self popToRootViewController];
```

Hope this helps you !!

Answer (score 1):

To do so make an interface for the home button

```
@interface stickyHomeButton :UIViewController

@end

@implementation stickyHomeButton

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BDSAppDelegate *mainDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UIButton  *homeButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [homeButton setFrame:homeButtonRect];
    //desing you home button as you want
    [homeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popToHomeViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [[mainDelegate window] addSubview:homeButton];
    [[mainDelegate window] bringSubviewToFront:homeButton];

}

-(void)popToHomeViewController
{
    [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

You are ready with you home button, now you need to do just a simple thing. all the viewController need to inherit `stickyHomeButton`

Answer (score 0):

Or you could add a container view, full screen size, and present your modals inside that as childrenViewControllers, with the static button above this container view in the hierarchy...